# Shed foundation out of square

Tags: foundation

I had a builder put up a raised 10x13 post and beam foundation in anticipation of a shed placement later. I measure it and find the diagonals are 4" off. What is the easiest way to adjust the rhombus back to square? Do I add a shim piece to the 6x6 posts on opposite corners?[image]

*Edit: Attaching another image to show exagerated shape and diagnals.  Also the 2x8 attached to the posts with lag bolts
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You mean, measuring the two horizontal diagonals gives you different values? (Please add some clarification to your question; thanks.)

Comment: Call the builder and ask them to correct their error at their expense.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing more about the framing. Please post photos or a more accurate description of the connections to the posts.

Comment: And technically it's not a [rhombus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus) since the sides aren't equal. It's a non-rectangular parallelogram. </pedantry>

Comment: For clarification, the framing is attached to the sides of the posts using lag bolts and not sitting on top.  The long sides are parallel also.

Comment: Can you add to your picture where the lag bolts are? and which direction it is out of square?

Comment: Ok, I added an image with the diagonals and corner attachment

Comment: What are the side measurements supposed to be (length & width)?  Two diagonally opposite corners would have to be brought in, with the other two shimmed out. With the expected measurements we can estimate how much they would need to move.  Will your municipality allow notching the support posts, or will they need to be torn out and replaced?  Definitely consult with the builder and tell him to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the sides are parallel, since you called it a rhombus, and the framing is attached to the sides of the post as the drawing seems to show:
You can definitely add shim pieces to the posts on the side that is at the top and bottom of your drawing. Depending on the load that the fasteners take, You may need to attach a block of some sort to support the end of the joist, since it won't be properly attached to the long side anymore.

You could also frame the walls square, and have them overhang the short corner.

Ideally, you should not finish paying the builder until he fixes it.

Comment: You can't "definitely add shims" without knowing something about the framing. If the flush beams are on top of the posts, shims do nothing. If there's building hardware involved, shims are also probably not an option. We need more info.

Comment: Added another qualification to my answer to clarify my interpretation of the drawing. It appears to show framing on the sides of the beams, not the tops.

Comment: I've seen other suggestions to just frame it square on top of the foundation.  With 2x6 footers I guess it would only overhang by a small amount.